# parse .mxl file with Clojure

Tags: xml, clojure, musicxml

I would like to parse an .mxl file (MusicXML) with clojure

So far i've seen a lot of tools to work with .xml files but I can't find a way to work with .mxl, maybe i should convert mxl to xml first but i don't know how to do that neither.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the file as XML? Based on the Wikipedia example it looks like it could be done.

Comment: i've got this exception:   SAXParseException Content is not allowed in prolog.  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException (ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)

Comment: The exception has probably nothing to do with the XML parsing code but with the file, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog) SO question for possible solutions on the exception you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page on MusicXML:

> The textual representation listed above is verbose; MusicXML v2.0 addresses this by adding a   compressed zip format with a .mxl suffix that can make files roughly one-twentieth the size of the uncompressed version.[16]

I'm guessing that your .mxl file is an XML file which has been compressed, and this is why you're getting parse errors. As far I can gather, the compression algorithm is a zip algorithm, so you should be able to use java's zip functionality to get at it.

**EDIT**

I just had a go at this with a sample .mxl file I found online. The .mxl file, once unzipped contained the xml file within it. I was then able to use following (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5428265/1037491)) to get the raw XML...

```clj
 (defn extract-mxl [path]
   (let [[_ filename] (re-matches #"(.*)\.mxl$" (.getName (java.io.File. path)))
         zipfile (java.util.zip.ZipFile. path)
         zipentry (.getEntry zipfile (str filename ".xml"))
         in (.getInputStream zipfile zipentry)] 
     (slurp in)))
```

Comment: it doesn't work... it seems that DeflaterInputStream (my edit) is for compress data , I should use InflaterInputStream for decompression but it doesn't work...

Comment: I've edited after testing with an .mxl I found...sorry about the previous code not working!

Comment: i've got this: java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream (ZipFile.java:194)

Comment: filename =>
"inv1"
zipfile => 
#<ZipFile java.util.zip.ZipFile@5070b2f8>
zipentry => 
nil
NullPointerException   java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream (ZipFile.java:194)

Comment: does the file .xml file is created or am i supposed to create manually? I am sorry but i don't understand much of Java Zip stuffs...

Comment: Try unzipping the file manually and seeing what's in there. The above code assumes that the <filename>.mxl, when unzipped contains <filename>.xml.

Comment: Ok I see... i've changed the filename before trying your code :) it works now! thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1):

MusicXML's zip structure for .mxl files is similar to that of the EPUB format. See http://www.musicxml.com/tutorial/compressed-mxl-files/zip-archive-structure/ in the MusicXML tutorial for more information about where to find the XML score data within the MXL archive.

Answer (score 0):

if someone stumbles upon this, and can't figure out how to unzip the compressed mxl file:

on mac, I just renamed it to .zip and it worked out fine!